# dns settings to connect godady domain to my hostgator

Tags: dns, godaddy-api

I have purchased a domaine `ex.com` .
 i set the cname and A record with www.
I did not change the default nameservers of godady.

if I type `http://ex.com` I can accses the website.
if I type `http://www.ex.com or https://www.ex.com`  I get 404

how can I resolve this?
my records..
[image: h]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a 404 error after configuring a CNAME alias for a subdomain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89948/getting-a-404-error-after-configuring-a-cname-alias-for-a-subdomain)

Comment: thank you I found a solution by pointing the cname to the record using @ symbol instead of hostgator url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, 
I just changed the cname pointing value to @ symbol insted of hostgator url.
this will redirect your server to the place (IP) that your A record pointing to.

[image]